# CasperJS - Click button based on value stored in variable

Tags: javascript, casperjs

Based on the input variable "feeling", I would like to click a button (good,bad or ok). How do i specify the input variable in casper.click?

```
var feeling = 'bad'; //User can choose good, bad or ok
.
.
logit_feeling(feeling); //fucntion call
.
.
// fucntion defnition
var logit_feeling = function (feeling){
    casper.then(function (){
        casper.click(x('//*[text()='feeling']'));   
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to properly quote and build the string that you would pass to the XPath helper:

```
x('//*[text()="'+feeling+'"]')
```

Oftentimes HTML is written with a lot of whitespace which is not shown when it is rendered. You would need to make this a little more robust:

```
x('//*[contains(text(),"'+feeling+'")]')
```

Answer (score 0):

kbet,

As the Artjom said, you can concatenate its variable in the XPath string and get the property element text ().

In some cases, you can still pursue, as well as the axes text () as may search for **. **.

For example:

```
'//a[.,"sample"]'
```

As above, the text is accurate as at the string. You can even compare some of the text, using the CONTAINS:

```
'//a[contains(.,"sample")]'
```

Another option you may consider is using casper.click () with the CSS path element (if you can):

```
casper.click("my > css > path");
```

I hope you can help! ;)

Comment: @kbet The list of Axes and properties, see http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_nodes.asp